# Crontab won't run sed shell

Tags: shell, sed, cron

I have a cron job to run a sed shell called sedcmd.sh to pre-process some json data. When i am in the proper directory I manually run it with

```
. ./sedcmd.sh
```

And it works. The shell itself works fine. 
for reference one of the commands inside looks like

```
sed -i '/^\s*$/d' /home/school/Desktop/Programs/rawjsondata.txt
```

my cronjob looks like

```
5 * * * * . ./home/school/Desktop/Programs/sedcmd.sh
```

I get the error "No such file or directory found". What am I doing wrong. I've triple checked for any random spelling errors. I also can't seem to run sedcmd.sh from any other directory even when i give the entire file path, so its definitely something I'm doing wrong. My thoughts for solutions are either

1. I should add sedcmd.sh to my $PATH or bashrc so i can call it from anywhere. Which I don't know how to do.
   OR
2. figure out how to call it correctly from crontab. Which I also dont know how to do.

Comment: What if you change the contrab entry to `5 * * * * /home/school/Desktop/Programs/sedcmd.sh` (without dots)?

Comment: that fixed it. why is that though? i thought the dots were necessary to call a shell.

Comment: Only if you are calling a file in the same directory you are. Have a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4432)

Comment: @JoaoMorais : Your advise was correct, but your reason is wrong. the call `. /path/to/scriptdir/sedcmd.sh` is a alias for `source /path/to/scriptdir/sedcmd.sh`. `source` or `.` runs the specified script in the current environment, and  any env. vars that are set inside of `sedcmd.sh` (in this case), are now **available to the current shell process**. If the env cmds are like `export var=value` then `$var` is exported to all subshells of the main process. (but not the parent, as if often wished for). Good luck to all.

Comment: @Sam : so in conclusion, general practice is to set project specific variables inside a sourced script at the top, using `. /path/to/scriptToSource` or `source /path/to/scriptToSource` . Generally usage like `source ./scriptToSource` is avoided, because the script must exist in the current dir of the process. Scripts executed from crontab like `./script` are most likely in the $HOME dir of the crontab entry owner. So you can't rely on that. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are running a script from terminal, you do:
`./script_name.sh` but to execute the same script from crontab you do something like `5 * * * * /path/to/script/script_name.sh`

As Sam has got this answer from the comments,posting the answer as community wiki.